# javascript and spread operator as unexpected token

Tags: javascript

I have strange problem with spread operator. When I use this code in chrome console, it works great:

```
var obj1 = { food: 'pizza', car: 'ford' }
var obj2 = { animal: 'dog' }

const merged = { 
  ...obj1,
  ...obj2
};
```

...but when I use it in my project in VSC, I'm getting an error

[image]

unexpected token is indicated in `...obj1`

Does someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Can you post your Babel config, since the error is coming from babel-loader?

Comment: Looks like you use an old babel-loader or config with old input version, as object literal spread is a rather recent addition to the language.

Comment: yea I used npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0

Comment: where can I find babel.config? I use webpack and I have babel files only in node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My `babel.config.js` had Chrome 58 as a target. According to [this browser support table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility), spread in object literals are only supported in Chrome 60 and onwards.

To fix this, you either need to increase your minimum supported browser version, or change your code.